# Given $f(x) = (\log(x))^2/(1+x^2)$, show that $f(z)$ vanishes as strongly as $1/z$ for $|z|\to \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics

**Context**

Let $$f(x) = \frac{(\log(x))^2}{1+x^2}.$$
I am trying to evaluate
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx.$$
However, the technique of complex analysis that I  using requires that $f(z)$ vanishes as strongly as $1/z$ for $|z|\to \infty$.  I do not know how to determine the asymptotic behavior.

So far, I have plotted the integral along with $1/x$. The slope of the two seem similar at very large $x$.  In addition, I have looked on Wikipedia and wolfram alpha for series representations at infinity. I found nothing useful. This is not the first time that I have had this problem (i.e. the asymptotic behavior of a function).  Yet, I am still unclear on the matter.

**Question**

What are the techniques one uses to determine asymptotic behavior? Can you apply this technique to this problem as an exemplar?

Comment: Why you write "$\displaystyle f(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^{2}(x)}{1+x^{2}}\, {\rm d}x$"? If the improper integral converges so it's just a numerical value. In fact, in this case we have the improper integral converges and the values is $\pi^{3}/8$.

Comment: @user1027216 I fixed it for the OP.

Comment: @Gary thank you so much. Now it's make sense for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following: For $x >1$ we have $\log x =3\log x^{1/3} <3x^{1/3}$. You get $f(x) <\frac 9 {x^{4/3}}$ better than the bound you asked for. [I have used the fact that $\log x <x$ for $x >1$]. (In fact, $\log x <x-1$!).

Comment: Can you add a citation for this? Can you explain your rationale?

Comment: $\log(z)=\log|z|+i\arg(z)\ll \log|z|\ll |z|^\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ and $|z|$ large enough.

Comment: @MichaelLevy For $w>0$, $$
e^w  = 1 + w + \frac{{w^2 }}{2} +  \cdots  > w \Rightarrow w > \log w.
$$ Use this with $w=x^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $z\in (\Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R)\cup \Bbb R^+,$ and $\log z=(\ln |z|)+i\arg z,$ with $\arg z\in (-\pi,\pi)$:

For  $|z|>e^{\pi}$ we have $|(\log z)^2|=|(\log z)|^2\le ((\ln |z|)+\pi)^2<4(\ln |z|)^2.$

For $|z|>2$ we have $|z^2+1|\ge |z^2|-|1|=|z|^2-1>|z|^2/2.$

Therefore $ |z|>e^{\pi}\implies 
|f(z)|<8\dfrac {(\ln |z|)^2}{|z|^2}$.

And of course $\ln |z|<|z|^{1/3}$ for all sufficiently large $|z|$.

Comment: I do not follow why $... <4(\ln|z|)^2)$.

Comment: I do not see how you obtain the statement that appears after "and of course'"

Comment: There are many ways to show that $\ln x$ grows more slowly than $x^r$ for any $r>0$ as $x\to\infty.$ E.g. for a fixed $n$ with $0<1/r<n\in\Bbb N$ and $x>e$ then $x^r>x^{1/n}=$ $=[\exp(\ln x)]^{1/n}>$ $[(\ln x)^n/n!]^{1/n}=$ $(\ln x)/(n!^{1/n}).$